# How to sort a complicated date value in react js table from the api

Tags: reactjs, database, algorithm, sorting, datatable

I am using react js to sort the date value. Its supposed to sort the date asc and desc when I click on the date column header. However, it doesnt sort it out. It just stays the same. I tried looking for answers but everyone has a different method and code base and it makes it difficult to implement. I was able to sort by id using the same method, however, with the date column, it doesnt sort it out.

[image]

```
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import { withStyles, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [idDirection, setIdDirection] = useState("asc");
  const [nameDirection, setNameDirection] = useState("asc");
  const [yearDirection, setYearDirection] = useState("asc");

  useEffect(async () => {
    await axios
      .get("https://data.nasa.gov/resource/gh4g-9sfh.json?$limit=15")
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data);
        console.log(res.data);
      });
  }, []);

  const StyledTableCell = withStyles((theme) => ({
    head: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
      color: theme.palette.common.white,
    },
    body: {
      fontSize: 14,
    },
  }))(TableCell);
  const StyledTableRow = withStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      "&:nth-of-type(odd)": {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
      },
    },
  }))(TableRow);
  const useStyles = makeStyles({
    table: {
      minWidth: 700,
    },
  });

  const classes = useStyles();

  const sortById = () => {
    if (idDirection === "asc") {
      setData(
        data.slice().sort((a, b) => {
          console.log(a.id);
          return b.id - a.id;
        })
      );
      setIdDirection("desc");
    }

    if (idDirection === "desc") {
      setData(
        data.slice().sort((a, b) => {
          console.log(a.id);
          return a.id - b.id;
        })
      );
      setIdDirection("asc");
    }
  };

  const sortByName = () => {
    if (nameDirection === "asc") {
      setData(
        data.slice().sort((a, b) => {
          console.log(a.name);
          return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
        })
      );
      setNameDirection("desc");
    }

    if (nameDirection === "desc") {
      setData(
        data.slice().sort((a, b) => {
          console.log(a.name);
          return b.name.localeCompare(a.name);
        })
      );
      setNameDirection("asc");
    }
  };

  const sortByYear = () => {
    if (yearDirection === "asc") {
      setData(
        data.slice().sort((a, b) => {
          console.log(a.year);
          return b.year - a.year;
        })
      );
      setYearDirection("desc");
    }

    if (yearDirection === "desc") {
      setData(
        data.slice().sort((a, b) => {
          console.log(a.year);
          return a.year - b.year;
        })
      );
      setYearDirection("asc");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <StyledTableCell onClick={() => sortById("id")} align="right">
                ID
              </StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell onClick={() => sortByName("name")} align="right">
                Name
              </StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">Rec Class</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">Name Type</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell onClick={() => sortByYear("year")} align="right">
                Year
              </StyledTableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {data.map((item) => (
              <StyledTableRow key={item.id}>
                <StyledTableCell align="right">{item.id}</StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="right">{item.name}</StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="right">{item.recclass}</StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="right">{item.nametype}</StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="right">{item.year}</StyledTableCell>
              </StyledTableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting the difference between two dates you need to first change the value of year to a date object. Try this for your `sortByYear` method.

```
const sortByYear = () => {
  if (yearDirection === "asc") {
    setData(
      data.slice().sort((a, b) => {
        console.log(a.year);
        return new Date(b.year) - new Date(a.year);
      })
    );
    setYearDirection("desc");
  }

  if (yearDirection === "desc") {
    setData(
      data.slice().sort((a, b) => {
        console.log(a.year);
        return new Date(a.year) - new Date(b.year);
      })
    );
    setYearDirection("asc");
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This did it!